# Can you mine remotely

Tags: mining-hardware, mining-reward

Is it possible to set up a rig in a location where you will only be once a few months, antminer. In summer temp may reach high 80s during day otherwise cooler temps... I wasn't sure what would go down if there is a power outage or if it gets too hot...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's certainly possible, there's nothing stopping you from doing so. You can easily manage mining hardware remotely with SSH. You can even leave the hardware unattended, but you might have some problems if there are issues that you have to actually start/stop the machines or deal with physical issues.

An option for remote management is colocation. With colocation, you let someone else manage your hardware and be physically on location with it. The hardware is anaged with other people's miners as well (hence the "co" part). Some colocation services will also allow you to remotely manage the hardware through SSH too and the people on location only deal with physical issues.

Comment: How can I find a collocation service? Thanks...

Comment: Use google. Many have websites or are announced on Bitcointalk or Reddit. Just search for "Bitcoin mining colocation".